# Evince keyboard shortcut to highlight text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, evince

Is there a keyboard shortcut to highlight text in Evince? To place a note? Or a way to setup a custom keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 9):

The feature was added just one month ago (August 10, 2018) to evince<sup>1</sup>. 
I guess it will be available in the next evince version 3.31. 
The shortcuts in the addition are <kbd>S</kbd> to add text annotation
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to add highlight annotations.
______________
<sup>1</sup> See [Merge Request “Allow Keybinding for highlighting annotation”](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/merge_requests/54).

Comment: It's too bad that some shortcuts are not documented at all. You need to look [at the source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/blob/674ab1de72145485f8ea2a715a6ff67a5c99548b/shell/ev-application.c#L944) to get know of them :/

Answer (score 0):

As my testing of evine,

1. press F11 to full screen mode,  press  ESC to go back
2. press F9 to toggle left side panel show, but you cannot do this if search box is shown
3. press ctrl + F to show search input box, press ESC to let it gone

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already, the keybindings `Ctrl` + `H` and `S` can be used to highlight and annotate text. However, this feature is present in evince 3.30+ [[1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/blob/gnome-3-30/NEWS#L181)] [[2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/merge_requests/54)]. Ubuntu 18.04 ships evince 3.28.

**So to get the keybindings in Ubuntu 18**, I installed the latest version of evince from snap, as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118796/how-do-i-install-evince-3-28-or-newer-on-ubuntu-xenial-16-04-lts) (currently it is 40.4 as opposed to apt's 3.28.4).