# Evince: Custom keyboard shortcuts to highlight text with different properties

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, evince

I regularly read pdfs and annotate them. I use three types of annotations: highlight (yellow), underline (red) and note. With Okular I can select the type of annotation easily, that is with a keyboard shortcut.

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471745/30019) I discovered Evince has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for highlight and <kbd>S</kbd> for Note, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to underline text. The only way I found is to highlight text and then change annotation properties.
Is there a way to add a shortcut to a custom annotation?